# How to submit form in struts2?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, tiles

I have following code in tiles.xml

```
<definition name="m_st"  extends="mmain">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="reports/st/list.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

And following code in struts.xml

```
<package name="m_st" namespace="reports/st" extends="struts-default, tiles-default">
    <action name="list" class="com.m.reports.StAction" method="list">
        <result type="tiles">m_st</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

And in list.jsp ,

```
<form name="rangeForm" method="post" action="">
```

In StAction.java,

```
private String type = "";

public String list() throws Exception {

    type = "TEST"; //listStandard.get(0).getStatus();

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

But when I click the submit button nothing happens, no error and no outputs. How to get the expected result like `<s:property value="type"/>` in list.jsp after submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty confusing question as worded. What are you actually doing? If you're in a plain old JSP, and the action is blank, you'll submit to the same JSP, and no action will execute.

If you actually mean that you're hitting the action and not seeing the property in the JSP, "why not" can depend on what version of S2 you're using (more precisely, what version of OGNL). For later versions, OGNL will access public fields directly, earlier versions require a public getter method.

Comment: I think my list() method in the StAction class is not called. How to execute the list() method when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="rangeForm" method="post" action="list">
```

You forgot to mention your action name.